# If blank in A, delete cells in column A to J

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to adapt my code now I've built out my sheet.

My code to clear the whole row is

```
Sub dontdeleteallrows()

Dim a
a = [MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(A1:A10000),0),0)]
If Not IsNumeric(x) Then Exit Sub
Rows(a & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete


End Sub
```

What can I replace `Rows(a & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete` with to delete cells AA to JA?

Comment: You got a fundamental issue here when variable `x` is used without being declared. Presumably you meant to use `a`?

Comment: @Sophie1372 could you be more specific? if column A is empty you want to delete or clear? The range you want to delete/clear is the whole line, columns A to J or AA to JA?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete the cells or clear them of content?

If you want to delete the cells, other content may need to move left or up. Where do you want it to go?

You might do something like

```
Range("Aa" & a & ":Ja" & a).clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check Column A for empty cell value and delete the entire row you could use the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find the last row
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop column A
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            'Check if cell is empty
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
                'Delete row
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```